# How do I make the computer take time to make a play in a game

Tags: java

I am making a game of Nim. I wish to make the computer take time to make a move to make the game feel more realistic rather than the computer instantly making a move back.

What happens in the computers move is that when the button is pressed the whole program just sleeps for 1.6 seconds and then both, players move and computers move are played at once.

```
public void playersMove() throws BadLocationException {
    lastPlayer = 0; //for winning check purposes
    try {
        playersStones = Integer.parseInt(txtfPlayer.getText()); // gets input from player
        if (playersStones <= 3 && playersStones >= 1) {
            isValid = true; // play is valid
            stonesLeft -= playersStones;
            logBox.append("You have taken " + playersStones + " stones.\nThere are: " + stonesLeft + " stones left.");
            if(stonesLeft != 0){ //if the game is over it does not say it's another person's turn
                logBox.append("\nIt is the computer's turn.\n\n");
            }
        } else {
            isValid = false; //play is not valid
            logBox.append("Please only take 1-3 stones!\n\n");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        isValid = false;//play is not valid
        logBox.append("Please only take 1-3 stones!\n\n");
    }
    winnerCheck(); // checks if player lost
}

public void computersMove() throws BadLocationException {
    if (isValid) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2300); // attempt to make the computer realistic
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        lastPlayer = 1; //for winning check purposes
        switch (stonesLeft) {
            //computer attempts to win
            //if winning moves not in range, will generate a random number to use
            case 1:
                stonesLeft = 0;
                logBox.append("The computer takes 1 stones.\n There are: 0 stones left.\n\n Y O U    H A V E    W O N\n\nPress the reset button to play a new game.");
                break;
            case 2:
                computersOutput(1);
                break;
            case 3:
                computersOutput(2);
                break;
            case 4:
                computersOutput(3);
                break;
            case 5:
                computersOutput(1);
                break;
            default:
                computersOutput((int) (Math.random() * (3 - 1 + 1) + 1));
                break;
        }
        winnerCheck(); //checks if computer lost
    }
}
private void buttonPlayActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        if(lastPlayer == 1 && !gameOver){  //player makes play
            playersMove();
            if(lastPlayer == 0 && !gameOver && isValid){ //only if play is valid computer plays
                computersMove();
            }
        }
        if(!isValid){
            playersMove();
            computersMove();
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {}
}
```

Comment: Try using timertask!

Comment: One thread = both stop. two threads = **BAM!!**

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right direction. But, the only problem I see is that the delay that you are introducing is static. So, A random delay that is not uniform for every move would be more appropriate in such circumstance.

Using the following snippet by setting appropriate minDelay and maxDelay values with integer values that indicate the number of seconds.

```
Thread.sleep(minDelay + (new Random.nextInt(maxDelay)*1000));
```

This would result in a variable delay between minDelay and maxDelay.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `java.swing.Timer` to let the computer wait for some time. First you need to import it of course. And then you need to write what you want to do when the timer "ticks":

```
ActionEvent action = new ActionEvent {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //do what you want here

    }
}
```

Now you create the timer:

```
final Timer t = new Timer (delayInMilliseconds, action);
```

And then you start it:

```
t.start();
```

Now when the timer ticks you want to stop it imediately so change the `actionPerformed` to this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //do what you want here
    t.stop();
}
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the whole program stops is because both the computer's moves and player's moves are happening on the same thread, so when you call Thread.sleep the entire thread falls asleep.

You can create another thread for the computer and have that thread sleep before making a move. When the computer is done making its move, you can join it back with your current thread to continue the game. You can read more about threads [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Here's a simple example:

```
public static class Computer implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        try {
        Thread.sleep(2300);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        // Implement computer's move here
    }
}

// In your main thread
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread computer = new Thread(new Computer());  // Create new computer

    // Implement player making his move here

    if(lastPlayer == 0 && !gameOver && isValid){
        computer.start();
    }

    computer.join(3000);  // Wait a maximum of 3 seconds for computer to finish its move

    // Continue with rest of program
}
```